# При входе на мой сайт он отображается как небезопасный

Tags: php, .htaccess, ocstore

Я настроил сертификат на `https://technikabishkek.kg`, но часть контента расположена на `upload.technikabishkek.kg` и браузер помечает страницы как небезопасные. Что нужно сделать, чтобы исправить проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для домена третьего уровня upload.ваш-сайт нужен свой собственный "валидный" сертификат, такой же как и для основного домена

или так называемый  wildcard для всех под-доменов сразу. Но это сложнее с обновлением, там нужно будет менять TXT запись в настройке DNS для продления.

> Если возможности создать сертификат нет, то можно рассмотреть вариант использования каталога сайта, вместо домена 3-го уровня `<ваш-сайт>/upload/`, также, можно использовать proxy c каталога на домен, если есть доступ к настройкам сервера). По мотивам [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/862610/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9#comment1393755_862615) **nick_n_a**.

Comment: Его нужно отдельно покупать?

Comment: нет, у вас используется бесплатный сертификат Let's Encrypt Authority X3, такой же (НЕ этот же, а такой же) можно использовать и для домена upload.*, сейчас ресурсы с этого домена просто блокируются. Если вы это делали через хостера, то обратитесь к нему. А в общем, да, сертификаты покупают/получают для каждого домена отдельно или wildcard на всё сразу.

Comment: Возможно проще будет ветку `upload.technikabishkek.kg` перебросить, например на `technikabishkek.kg/upload`

Comment: да, это тоже нормальный вариант